# Give some examples of documentation that talks about reentrancy attacks / recursive call vulnerabilities

Tags: attacks, reentrant-attacks, documentation

The DAO, a smart-contract on Ethereum, was vulnerable to reentrancy attacks and 3 million ETH worth $50 million was stolen from it.

What are some examples of content that mentions reentrancy attacks? Specifically, older content, as the content from June 2016 and forward is easily found through Google.

Does the [whitepaper](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper) or the [yellowpaper](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf) or other developer documentations mention reentrancy attacks ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are a developer or interested in recreating the attack, I've created two contracts for the purpose of demonstrating exactly how it worked. 
https://github.com/joeb000/mock-dao-hack

There are also some articles linked in the README file you might find helpful.

Comment: Great resource. This will be very useful to new developers when learning about reentrancy. 

My idea with this thread is to gather information about how widespread documentation and knowledge about reentrancy was prior to The DAO.

Answer (score 4):

**Before June 2016**

- August 2014: [Reentrant Contracts](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/1317/reentrant-contracts) gives an example of "a contract can be tricked into calling itself".
- July 2015: [LeastAuthority Ethereum Analyses](https://github.com/LeastAuthority/ethereum-analyses/blob/master/GasEcon.md) mentioned:

> reentrancy hazards if the callback itself executes publish(),
>   subscribe(), or unsubscribe(): repeated actions, missing actions, and
>   inconsistent delivery of messages

- November 2015: [How to write safe smart contracts](http://chriseth.github.io/notes/talks/safe_solidity/#/7) was a talk given at DevCon1, noting that sending money:

> always triggers execution of fallback function ( function() { ...} )
>
> → make fallback function cheap
>
> → prepare for callbacks (can mess up your state!)